# How to use EGit with SSH on Windows?

Tags: eclipse, git, ssh, egit

I am trying to import a git repository from remote into Eclipse 3.6 with EGit 2.1. I have generated a new SSH key and have also added the pub_key to authorized keys on server side. But I always get the error: `read time out`. - After Branch selection.

When I clone the repository with same credentials from cygwin or from git bash it works very well.

Has anybody an idea?

Comment: http://superuser.com is usually a better place to ask such kind of questions since they are not directly related to programming but with tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the remote connection timeout. Increasing it, has solved the problem:

```
Preferences --> Team --> Git: "Remote connections timeout (seconds): 99999999
```

Answer (score 5):

Does Eclipse see your new ssh keys ?

To check this open "Preferences > General > Network Connections > SSH2"

in tab "General":

- check if "SSH2 home" is pointing to your ~/.ssh folder
- check if private key is listed, otherwise add it

in tab "Key Management" try to load the (private) key you want to use